# How to know response media type using InputStreamResponseListener with Jetty

Tags: http, jetty

I would like to receive a HTTP response via stream using Jetty (`org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.InputStreamResponseListener`). However, I am not sure how to detect the content-type (i.e. media type) of the response in case of streaming response?

Using `org.eclipse.jetty.client.api.Request.send()` everything is clear because I can get the content type using `org.eclipse.jetty.client.api.ContentResponse.getMediaType()`. However, in case of streaming response there is no such method.

I was thinking of using the `org.eclipse.jetty.client.api.Response.getHeaders()` method. But I not sure what it will return. The documentation of Jetty does not say if this listener handles single HTTP response and/or a chunked response. In case of a chunked response there are several HTTP responses with potentially different (or missing) content types.

Which HTTP response is exactly returned by `org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.InputStreamResponseListener.get​(long timeout, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit unit)`? The first one?

If it is more ore less the same as for ContentResponse why does it not provide related methods for the content type?

I would like to avoid problems with missing or uncertain content types on client side for streaming content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of a `InputStream` via the `InputStreamResponseListener` to read the HTTP Response body content is all you need.

That `InputStream` is unaffected by the `Content-Type` response header values, even the mime media type or the charset.

That's because the `InputStream` is just raw bytes, it's up to you to take those raw bytes and apply the appropriate charset (if dealing with textual data instead of binary), decoding, unescaping, parsing to fit the needs of your application, using the hints provided by the `Content-Type` response header (mime-type and optional charset).